# using comma before 'no matter'

Tags: punctuation

I always thought when we use the dependent clause after the main clause, we don't need a comma before the subordinating conjunction for example,

> I always sneaked into the movies to see an R-rated **although** my parents never would've approved.

till I came across this sentence,

> [They kept the family farm, no matter how unprofitable it became.](http://hkrauthamer.tripod.com/Comma_rules.html)

The website says it's because the information remains true, no matter what you add in the subordinate clause.

I seem to fail to understand how you can add some information that make the comma unnecessary. Interestingly the same is true with *although*.

> He kept charging to his card, although his account was overdrawn.

How can I add some information that can change the main clause! Should I say something like,

> He kept charging to his card although he didn't!

I don't think so. So what's the trick? What's the point that I'm missing?

Comment: "He kept charging his card although he didn't" doesn't make sense.... with or without a comma.

Comment: @Catija i know. i don understand why it's the right punctuation anyway. when should i avoid using a comma and when not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The truth about commas is that all the rules are just guidelines to help structure your sentences for readability.  The *purpose* of the comma is to simulate the pause that would appear in the sentence if spoken.  It's never *required* but it often helps.

In this case the comma is most frequently used because a speaker would pause before "although" to indicate a change in the direction of the sentence.  For example:

> I really love a good steak, but my doctor says I have to cut back on eating red meat.

In a similar way, a speaker would pause to separate the things in a list:

> Is there anything in the world better than good wine, good friends, and good conversation?

Anyway, the rule you quote is a nice starting *guide*, but I wouldn't [take it as *gospel*.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+as+gospel)

Comment: So according to what you said, it's OK if I ignore it and go without comma in the second quoted sentence and it's actually **not** different from _"They kept the family farm no matter how unprofitable it became."_ (without a comma). Since generally we don't put comma before **subordinating conjunctions**, _but_ isn't one of them BTW so your example isn't really accurate. What does this pause imply before _although_?

Comment: my point is in some places you put a comma before _although, no matter, etc_ (i recently learnt that) and in some places before the **same** words you don't. why do you do this? what's the point? it seems in some places it's recommended some placed not. what are those occasions?

Comment: @Yuri  Some grammar rules must be followed, but the rules about commas aren't one of them.  As far as I know **all** of them relate to *style*, and using or not using a comma is about personal preference.  In most cases if it helps the flow of the sentence to use a comma, you should use it.  "Although" is always used to change the direction of a sentence, so imagine it being spoken out loud: "I love 80s movies ... although I wish they would stop making bad remakes."   The more familiar you get with how English is naturally spoken, the more natural the comma will seem to you.

Comment: i kept searching and found a [**site**](https://jakubmarian.com/comma-before-whereas-while-and-although/) that partially answered the whyness of presence and abscence of a comma before _although_. you might want to take a look at it.  i wonder if the same thing can be applied to _no matter_. i'll keep searching. Thank you for your time though +1

Comment: @Yuri I hope it helps, but as I said, I'd be careful of any site that tries to come up with "rules" for commas.  If you read authors who write in English, there is a wide range of styles -- some who use them frequently, and some who don't use them at all.

Answer (score 0):

In both above-mentioned sentences, the subordinate clauses are examples of sheer contrast, therefore a comma is used to clarify the writer's stance.

Example is as follows:

- > She is happy because she has won an Oscar.
- > She is not happy, although she has won an Oscar.

Comment: My problem is _i don't understand where using comma is logical and where it's not_ I quote from this website(1): "Punctuation with subordinators depends on **how essential** the added clause is to the overall meaning of the sentence. Does it make all the difference? Or is it only **added optional** information?
Comma for although/whereas. **Use a comma when the main sentence is true, no matter what you add**.
Comma: He kept charging to his card **,although** his account was overdrawn. (he kept charging regardless)"

Comment: [(1)](http://hkrauthamer.tripod.com/Comma_rules.html) Quoted. My question is when although adds optional information when essential... how should i know?!